# How to load data from database at the time of class loading by JVM and store it in List or Map for further use?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I am using spring and hibernate application, In my requirement I have to load data from database at the time of project deployement and store data in Map or List for further use in whole application. I have googled a lot but not found any solution.

Comment: What Container do you use? Tomcat? JBoss? ...

Comment: See if ServletContextListener helps you [http://www.journaldev.com/1945/servlet-listener-example-servletcontextlistener-httpsessionlistener-and-servletrequestlistener](http://www.journaldev.com/1945/servlet-listener-example-servletcontextlistener-httpsessionlistener-and-servletrequestlistener) have a look here

Answer (score 0):

try using a ServletContainerInitializer

https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/6/html/API_Documentation/files/javadoc/javax/servlet/ServletContainerInitializer.html

If this ServletContainerInitializer is bundled in a JAR file inside the WEB-INF/lib directory of an application, its onStartup method will be invoked only once during the startup of the bundling application.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
<prop key="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">true</prop>
```

In **hibernate configuration.xml**
to cache the data that you access from data base and store in object ... now if you use the same object anywhere in your application it will use the same cache and wil not hit the database again.

Another way is

you can configure the cache using the xml file, see the spring reference manual:

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/cache.html#cache-declarative-xml

```
<!-- the service we want to make cacheable -->
<bean id="service" class="x.y.service.MyService"/>

<!-- cache definitions -->
<cache:advice id="cacheAdvice" cache-manager="cacheManager">
<cache:caching cache="books">
<cache:cacheable method="getData" key="#id"/>
<cache:cache-evict method="loadData" all-entries="true"/>
</cache:caching>
</cache:advice>  

<!-- apply the cacheable behaviour to all dataService interfaces -->
<aop:config>
<aop:advisor advice-ref="cacheAdvice" pointcut="execution(* x.y.myService.*(..))"/>
</aop:config>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Better approach is to use Hibernate, In hibernate we have First Level cache.
First-level cache always Associates with the Session object. Hibernate uses this cache by default. Here, it processes one transaction after another one, means wont process one transaction many times. Mainly it reduces the number of SQL queries it needs to generate within a given transaction. That is instead of updating after every modification done in the transaction, it updates the transaction only at the end of the transaction.

First level cache retrieval example

In this example, I am retrieving DepartmentEntity object from database using hibernate session. I will retrieve it multiple times, and will observe the sql logs to see the differences.

//Open the hibernate session
Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
session.beginTransaction();

//fetch the department entity from database first time
DepartmentEntity department = (DepartmentEntity) session.load(DepartmentEntity.class, new Integer(1));
System.out.println(department.getName());

//fetch the department entity again
department = (DepartmentEntity) session.load(DepartmentEntity.class, new Integer(1));
System.out.println(department.getName());

session.getTransaction().commit();
HibernateUtil.shutdown();

Output:

Hibernate: select department0_.ID as ID0_0_, department0_.NAME as NAME0_0_ from DEPARTMENT department0_ where department0_.ID=?
Human Resource
Human Resource
As you can see that second “session.load()” statement does not execute select query again and load the department entity directly.
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all [you can't use any List or Map as Cache replacement](http://vladmihalcea.com/caching-best-practices/). You can use Hibernate Second Level Cache, or even an external caching solution as long as your data is not going to be modified, which might cause consistency issues.

So if teh cached data is read-only then you can safely cache it. Otherwise you need a read-write cache, and the second Level Cache is much more appropriate in this scenario.

Comment: Friend data caching is not my problem. Main issue is how to fetch data at the time of application start in hibernate. Using JDBC I can do it.

Comment: You can use a Spring @PostConstruct listener which has the SessionFactory injected. When the init is running you can open a Session and load your entities.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to load the collection at time of class loading you can make use of immediate fetching or eager loading strategy in Hibernate. According to eager loading, when you make any collection as eagerly loaded lets suppose-->

If Foo has a Collection, and you set it to lazy, then only when you need the contents fo that collection are the selected, loaded, etc. **whereas if it is eager, it will load the Bars at the time it loads Foo**. This can be problematic if you eagerly load a collection of entities that eagerly load a collection of entities, and so on.
But I suppose in your case the Fetch Type = eager strategy will work and it will load at the time the class is loaded.

An Example : 
    @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name="countryId")
    private Set states;